# Tela "loading" na activity

Tags: android

Gostaria de poder saber ou entender como se coloca na tela um loading. 
Meu app faz consulta em um webservice, e as vezes dependendo da conexão ele demora para trazer as informações. E o app fica todo branco. Para o usuário final parece que travou. Então gostaria de colocar uma tela de loading.

Código de requisição HTTP

```
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://LINK DO MEU Json";
private static Retrofit mRetrofit;
private static ApiNOMEDOPROJETORequestInterceptor mInterceptor;
private static Gson mGson;
private static OkHttpClient mClient;

public static Retrofit getInstance() {
    if (mRetrofit == null) {
        //create Gson
        mGson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                .create();

        //create interceptor
        mInterceptor = new ApiNOMEDOPROJETORequestInterceptor();


        //create httpClient with interceptor
        mClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(mInterceptor).build();

        //create retrofit
        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(mGson))
                .client(mClient)
                .build();
    }
    return mRetrofit;
}
```

}

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o código que faz a consulta ao webservice.

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi, esse todo branco que o aplicativo fica durante o procedimento é porque não tem realmente informação na tela. Certo? Caso não seja por isso, mas porque a tela travou, a solução começa colocando a requisição ao web service em uma thread separada. Sobre a questão da sua tela de loading, particularmente, eu não criaria uma tela para isso, mas usaria um ProgressBar, exibindo quando a requisição iniciasse e escondendo quando ela fosse finalizada. Por favor, nos mostre seu código como o @ramaral solicitou para podermos te mostrar um exemplo.

Comment: @YoungerAuad acho que o que eu preciso é isto mesmo. Vou editar a minha pergunta e colocar o código da requisição.

Comment: Tem que capturar os dados do webservice em segundo plano, senão a tela fica travada esperando acabar a requisição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia Artur, provavelmente você usa a classe async pra fazer esta conexão, tente usar o código abaixo. Quando chama a classe ela mostra um Dialog pro usuário, espero ter ajudado.

```
public abstract class AsyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected final Context mContext;
    protected final String mMsqInfo;
    protected ProgressDialog mDialog;

public AsyncData(String msgInfo, Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mMsqInfo = msgInfo;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    if (mIsShowDialog){
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_label_wait);
        mDialog.setMessage(mMsqInfo);
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mDialog.show();
    }
}



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // seu código...
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
    super.onPostExecute(results);
    if ((mDialog != null) && ( mDialog.isShowing()) {

        mDialog.dismiss();
        mDialog = null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Arthur - xará - você viu o código que postei depois ?